# Best approach to display query with join in a search container

Tags: sql, join, liferay

I have a search page for books. I can search by title or by category (in my model a book is linked to a unique category). When I display the results I would like to display the category name also. Here is what I did:

```
    <liferay-ui:search-container-results>
    <%
        searchContainer.setTotal(BookLocalServiceUtil.searchBooksCount(title, categoryId));
        searchContainer.setResults(BookLocalServiceUtil.searchBooks(title, categoryId));
    %>
    </liferay-ui:search-container-results>
    <liferay-ui:search-container-row
        className="example.Book"
        keyProperty="bookId"
        modelVar="book" escapedModel="<%= true %>"
    >
        <portlet:renderURL var="editURL">
            <portlet:param name="mvcPath" value="/html/book/edit_book.jsp" />
            <portlet:param name="bookId" value="<%= String.valueOf(book.getBookId()) %>" />
        </portlet:renderURL>

        <liferay-ui:search-container-column-text
            name="Book"
            value="<%= String.valueOf(book.getTitle()) %>"
            href="<%= editURL %>"
        />

        <liferay-ui:search-container-column-text
            name="Category"
            value="<%= CategoryLocalServiceUtil.getCategory(book.getCategoryId()).getName() %>"
        />
    </liferay-ui:search-container-row>
```

This is not optimized at all. The best way to do that would be to write a custom SQL with a join but I can't because I have optional parameters in my query (book title and category).
Any idea?

**EDIT** here is my current query:

```
public List<book> searchBooks(String title, Long categoryId) 
        throws SystemException {
    DynamicQuery dynamicQuery = DynamicQueryFactoryUtil.forClass(Book.class);
    if (Validator.isNotNull(title)) {
        dynamicQuery.add(PropertyFactoryUtil.forName("title").eq(title));
    }
    if (Validator.isNotNull(categoryId)) {
        dynamicQuery.add(PropertyFactoryUtil.forName("categoryId").eq(categoryId));
    }
    List<Book> lst = BookLocalServiceUtil.dynamicQuery(dynamicQuery);
    return lst;     
}
```

Comment: How does your query look like and what is your DB Server? It's very easy to handle optional parameters.

Comment: I'm using PostgreSQL. Handle optional parameters is not really the problem. To get the category name I'd like to make a join but as far as I know I can't do it with a dynamic query. That's why I thought to create a custom SQL query, but then I have the pb of optional parameters... (I edit my original post to show the current query).

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to handle optional parameters is to treat the null as a non filtering value.

As you didn't say which RDBMS are using I'm showing a sample of a predicate with T-SQL syntax:

```
WHERE (@Title = Book.Title  -- filtering
       OR @Title IS NULL)   -- not filtering f the parameter is null
AND   (                     -- chain expressions like the expression above
```

*Please, note that this is not optimum. If you have performance problems it has to do with the way severs tretat this query: they usually are not smart enough to realize that, if the parameter is null, they don't need to evaluate the first part of the OR expression*

Comment: I'm using PostgreSQL but the idea is to not rely on a RDBMS, right?